# Implement modal close on click outside

Tags: javascript, preact

I've been trying to implement an onclick modal close in my system. I already implemented a modal onclick event using a close button but haven't done it successfully when clicking outside the modal

I already tried adding onclick listener on the div but the content is closing even clicking inside the modal window.

```
<div
                className={"Overlay " + (this.state.hidden? "hidden": "show")}
                id={this.props.id + "-container"} onClick={() => {
                this.setState({ hidden: true })
            }}>
```

here's my modal box rendering code so far

```
 render() {
        const contentClassName = this.getContentClassName();

        if (this.props.show) {
            document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        }

        const contentStyle = {
            width: this.props.width,
            height: this.props.height,
            position: "relative"
        };

        return (
            <div
                className={"Overlay " + (this.state.hidden? "hidden": "show")}
                id={this.props.id + "-container"} onClick={() => {
                this.setState({ hidden: true })
            }}>
                <div className={contentClassName}>
                    <div className={"Overlay-container"} style={contentStyle}>
                        <a id={this.props.id + '-closeButton'}
                           className="Overlay-closeBtn icon-close-zoom" onClick={() => {
                               this.setState({ hidden: true })
                        }}/>
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

as expected i want the modal to be close when clicking outside the modal window. currently it's closing even after clicking the modal window.

Comment: onclick of the child(cointainer), use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`. Also read about `event bubbling`.

Comment: i will read this one

Comment: So basically what's happening here is, when you click inside the modal, the `onclick` event is bubble up to parent div, where you are hiding the modal. i.e the listener of parent gets fired and hence the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$('html').click(function(e) {
        if(!$(e.target).hasClass("Overlay-container")) {
             document.getElementById('Overlay-container').style.display = "none" 
        } 
});
</script>
```

your code switch the state show or hidden when you click on it(Of course you can't click closed one)

This function works when your click has no class element named "Overlay-container"

//add description
when you click your 'html', 'if' checks where you clicked and has class 'Overlay-container'.
And if there's no 'Overlay-container' on your click point, modal close.

Comment: it's not like this, i want to close the opened modal box by clicking anywhere outside

Comment: this is for clicking outside :D

Comment: I will try it :D

Comment: This will only work if the OP is using JQuery.  Currently, the OP only talks about Javascript and Preact.

Comment: well yes, so i will need to convert it first

Answer (score 1):

Manage to solved this by doing this one

```
onClickOutside(e){
        if (e.target.classList.contains('Overlay-content') || e.target.classList.contains('Overlay-container')) {
            this.setState({
                hidden: true
            })
        }
    }
```

```
<div
                className={"Overlay " + (this.state.hidden? "hidden": "show")}
                id={this.props.id + "-container"}>
                <div className={contentClassName} onClick={(e)=>{
                    this.onClickOutside(e);

                }}>
                    <div className={"Overlay-container"} style={contentStyle}>
                        <a id={this.props.id + '-closeButton'}
                           className="Overlay-closeBtn icon-close-zoom" onClick={(e) => {
                               this.onClickHide(e)
                        }}/>
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thanks!